# My computer can't mount the / drive

Tags: partitioning

I was looking at my drives trying to fix a slight problem and now I can't get back into my computer

So if there's a way to reset the settings for the drive WITHOUT being able to get to the settings  can some one tell me how do so
Thanks

Comment: Please try to give more information on what you changed where, at the moment your question is to vague to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to boot a live ubuntu and revert the changes.

You provide insufficient information what you changed and happens on boot.

Comment: Welcome to AU!  We're glad you're here at work answering questions.  Would you mind expanding this answer a bit?  It's not clear how the OP would revert the changes.